# How to make tail function return what I need?

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml, run-length-encoding

I need to encode list in OCaml. Command: `encode ['a','a','b','b','b','c'];;` have to return `[(2,'a');(3,'b');(1,'c')]`

Now I have this function:

```
let encode list =
  let rec encodeHelper list acc = 
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | head :: [] -> (1, head) :: []
    | head :: headNext :: tail -> 
        if head = headNext then 
          encodeHelper (headNext :: tail) (acc + 1)
        else 
          (acc, head) :: encodeHelper (headNext :: tail) acc
  in encodeHelper list 1
;;
```

But it returns:

- : (int * (char * char * char * char * char * char)) list =
  [(1, ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'))]

Comment: Btw, the `head :: []` case should use the `acc`umulator, not `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test data as shown at the top is not in the right form.

A list in OCaml has elements separated by semicolons (`;`). Your test data is using commas instead (`,`). Commas are used for tuples, which is why you're seeing a tuple in your result.

If you change `,` to `;` in your test data you should see something closer to what you're looking for. There is at least one problem left to fix (in my testing).